# can't access excel file if I don't alert the values first in the javascript step

Tags: javascript, apache-poi, pentaho, kettle

I have some specific values that I need to write on specific cells in excel. I do this on the javascript step, what I do is i get the path first and then the name of the sheet. and then i do the modifications necessary.

the weird thing that happens is that, if i don't output the filename path and the sheetname first before accessing the file, I can't access the sheet and when I try to it says the sheet is null and my attempt to initialize or access a row fails.

```
var fii = new java.io.FileInputStream( targetFile );
var excelWorkbook = new org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook( fii );
var excelSheet = excelWorkbook.getSheet(getVariable('NEW_PRODUCT_NAME', 'noValue'));
```

this is the error message

```
 TypeError: Cannot call method "getRow" of null (script#32)
```

script#32 is trying to do the sheet.getRow method

BUT the weird thing is that when I try to alert the targetFile (complete filename and path) and the sheetname first, just right before making the reference it works perfectly fine and I don't encounter any errors.

i'm just not sure why is that. any ideas or suggestions please?

EDIT:

the excel that I am trying to access is also dynamically created in the same transformation.

Comment: You don't appear to have any code that fetches the sheet from your `excelWorkbook` object - could it be as simple as that?

Comment: i'll include that on the edit. actually i already figured it out. seems like the creation of the file and the accessing of the file kinda conflicts because the application tried to access the file but the script still can't see the file. i don't know why, i have a blocking step but it still happens. will post complete answer when i can

Answer (score 0):

I still need to manually put a delay on the set of transformations even though I already have a blocking step before I access the file. the blocking step's value is the transformation that creates the file.

I used the script here

http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/2010/07/writing-to-multiple-excel-sheets-with-kettle/